# questions about re.sub() in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the string like this `"css/login.css"` to `"***css/login.css***"`,the whole string is this:

```
str1 = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0">\
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/login.css"/>\
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>\
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>\
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/authLogin.js"></script>\
</head>'
```

this is my code:

`pattern1 = r'.*?href.*?=.*?(".+?\.css").*?'
 re.sub(pattern1,r"***\1***",str1)`

and the output is:

```
'***"css/login.css"***/>\t<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery.js">
</script>\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js">
</script>\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/authLogin.js">
</script></head>'
```

why it doesn't output the string before the `"css/login.css"/>`,that is `'<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0">\<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href =`?

Hope anyone can help,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the part before the first capture group to be reproduced in your output, then you need to create a capture group for that also. Similarly for the trailing part, you could create a capture group (but remove the lazy `?`)

```
pattern1 = r'(.*?href.*?=.*?)(".+?\.css")(.*)'
re.sub(pattern1, r"\1***\2***\3", str1)
```

If you have newlines in your input string, then you should also use the `re.DOTALL` flag, so these newline characters are matched with the `.*` you have:

```
pattern1 = r'(.*?href.*?=.*?)(".+?\.css")(.*)'
re.sub(pattern1, r"\1***\2***\3", str1, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) the function re.sub is described as follows:

```
Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of
pattern in string by the replacement repl.
```

In your regular expression, the first `.*` matches against everything before the `href` in your string. Then everything up to and including `"css/login.css"` in your string is part of the pattern that you specify with your regular expression.
This then gets replaced with `***"css/login.css"**`.